# Simple Ionic workflow, does it work with backend without API?

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

This probably seems stupid question. But I'm new to ionic apps. I wanted to clear this before development.

Can we build ionic app without API? like we normally do for our website.

**Example:**
If you go to MySite.com, you will see the site running in php with normal rendering. Would Ionic work same way or it has to go through API Send/Receive request for data handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic has no direct requirement on data access. It is built on AngularJS, which is in turn built on Javascript. Best practices would generally have you accessing JSON data from a server by using a mechanism that is Angular aware such as $http, $resource, Restangular, etc.

However, you can execute any javascript based browser command (or even load something like jQuery to perform the data access). However, as soon as you go outside of Angular, then you will have to deal with the additional complexity of making sure the digest cycle is run whenever you have updated values that may be reflected on your view because of data binding.

And, just to be clear, none of this has anything to do with what's happening on the server side. When you are asking about accessing "without API", do you mean accessing HTML files vs. JSON data? Ionic is built to be a SPA (single page application) that is installed on the mobile device and doesn't require internet access to run once it's installed.

Therefore, especially if external/live data isn't required (imagine some type of calculator where you enter values and results can be calculated with just the data in the app on the handset -- without the need for a live server at all), Ionic apps don't REQUIRE access to an external server at all.

You could provide traditional hyperlinks to other html files, but at that point it would no longer be running the packaged/installed files that form the basis of the installed app on the handset and would instead be a web app that is relying on an external server for all views. And, of course, even if it does require access to data from a server, the often massive increase in speed by not round tripping the server with a new HTML page (only a relatively tiny JSON payload in most situations) makes it feel much more like a true native app.

Comment: The reason for using app (but as webapp in same time), it will be quick integration. but with Rest API will require development of API (which is not a problem), but then managing authentication with token. that would also need to be developed.  Quick launch would be as native app which will run web app. the only issue I see is what you mention about being slow on rendering, due to load time.  Have you ever tried native app as webapp?

Comment: If you have a fully functional, mobile friendly web app already, and you just want to deploy it as a native/hybrid app, it sounds like you don't need Ionic. You could just use Cordova/PhoneGap to deploy it as a hybrid app, but avoid Ionic. In general, if you're not going to use and benefit from Angular, Ionic is probably not the best mobile framework for you.

Comment: web app also uses angular but without API. Thank you. I will check more into hybrid app. I wanted to also use mobile mobile latitude and longitude continuously as mobile move. like tracking car.

Answer (score 0):

In ionic, the rendering happens on your phone. The server simply provides data. So if you need any data from a server (usually yes) then you need an API.

> Ionic is focused on building native/hybrid mobile apps rather than
>   mobile websites.
>
> – http://ionicframework.com/docs/overview/#browser-support

As per definition, an API only defines the way your ionic app can interact with your php script. In principle, there are no rules on how you design this interaction. So yes, you can keep it quite traditional/old-fashioned. Don't get the concept of an API mixed up with the concepts of RESTful or SOAP APIs etc.

Comment: Sorry, I mean to ask. can we connect ionic directly with php scripts (data) without API? like we do for web applications?